# How to use protobuf to deserialize string between c# and java?

Tags: protocol-buffers

In c#，i use protobuf-net to serialize a string to byte array and send it through network

```
var bytes = Serializer.SerializeObject("Hello,world")
```

this byte array contains 13 elements, includes 2 prefix tags, start with 0x10, then 0x0b for string length.

i tried to deserialize in java, I use ByteString to convert that byte array to string, i got an error string: \n Hello,world!
this means that java does not ignore the prefix tags.

anybody knows why? thx!

Answer (score 0):

The protobuf format doesn't allow for naked data, so protobuf-net interprets `Serializer.Serialize("Hello, world")` as though it were a message of the form:

```
message Foo {
    optional value = 1;
}
```

and as if you had - in C# terms - used:

```
Serializer.Serialize(new Foo { value = "Hello, world") });
```

The 0x10 is the field marker for field 1, etc.

If you ever want to check the internals of an encoded message without knowing the schema, this tool may help: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode